# java: incompatible types:class cannot be converted to T, Here compiler is expecting us to cast the object to T

Tags: java, generics

The following function throws "java: incompatible types: java.lang.Integer cannot be converted to T compilation" error while returning the Integer object directly or by assigning it to t. By type erasure, arguments should be of type Number, and Integer, being a subclass of Number, should be able to accept it. I'm not sure why we have to cast it to T before assigning the integer to the variable t.

```
public class Tester
{

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        int i = calculate(1);
        System.out.println(i + " <--");

        //Number n = new Integer(1);
    }

    public static <T extends Number> T  calculate(T t){

        System.out.println(t.shortValue());
        t = new Integer(t.intValue());
        return t;
    }

}
```

Comment: Type erasure is at runtime. But the compiler has to make sure you don't return an `Integer` when, for example, a `Double` is expected.

Comment: As given, the return type should be `Integer`, not `T`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, the purpose of your method is to extract an integer part from an arbitrary subtype of `Number`.

For that, you don't need to reassign the method parameter `t` (*and in general, it's not a good practice*). And there's no need to use constructor of `Integer` class (*which is by the way **deprecated***), since Java 1.5 we have [autoboxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html), and you don't need to worry about conversion between wrapper types and primitives.

Method [`Number.intValue()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Number.html#intValue()) gives you a primitive `int` value, simply return it from the method.

```
public static <T extends Number> int calculate(T t) {
    
    return t.intValue();
}
```

*Usage example:*

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int i1 = calculate(1);
    int i2 = calculate(9.95);
    int i3 = calculate(new BigDecimal("10000000.971519"));
}
```